# jquery ajax to php script not saving data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have the following jQuery ajax call to a php script:

```
actualHtml = $('div').html(); // could this line be causing an issue?
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'save-html-css-action.php',
        data: { 
           'htmlTextToSave': htmlTextToSave,
           'actualHtml': actualHtml,
           'userId':userId
        },
        success: function(msg){
            alert(msg);
        }
});
```

php:

```
$htmlCssToSave = $_POST['htmlTextToSave'];
$userId = $_POST['userId'];
$actualHtml = $_POST['actualHtml'];


$mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $sqlusername, $sqlpassword, $dbname);

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    //printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
     echo "Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}


    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO user_saved_data (user_html_css_code, dd_id, actual_html) values ('".$htmlCssToSave."',".$userId.",'".$actualHtml."')");
    echo "success";

    /* close connection */
    $mysqli->close();
```

but when I check the database, the data isn't there. Am I doing something wrong in the `jquery/php` combo (meaning the ajax call)? I'm getting a javascript "success" alert, so it's hitting the script, but I'm not sure why the info isn't being inserted.

The table datatypes are medium text for both the `htmlcsstosave` and the `actualhtml` columns, and int for userid (not the primary key, this is a foreign key to another table)

so I added a an error alert and this is the output

> > You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'margin-0'> 
> >                             <head>
> >                             </head> 
> >                             <body cl' at line 1

Comment: Go ahead and find out why, `if(!$mysqli->query(....your query)){ echo $mysqli->error; } ` Also, you're accepting user input and should be using `prepared statements` to help fight `sql injection`.

Comment: nice, thanks for this debug tip, I'll try it now

Comment: .. this is gonna be fun, I'm trying to save html, and its saying bad syntax at somewhere, will update the question as I'm not sure what exactly the syntax it doesn't like is

Comment: No need. Simply change to prepared statements and you'll be good.

Comment: No need to go digging; I've provided you with the prepared solution below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we discussed, the issue is with escaping and sanitizing data. If you used prepared statements, it will handle it for you. let's have a look at how that would work:

Prepare the statement:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO user_saved_data (user_html_css_code, dd_id, actual_html) values (?,?,?)");
```

Bind your parameters:

```
$stmt->bind_param('sis', $htmlCssToSave, $userId, $actualHtml);
```

Then execute your statement:

```
$stmt->execute();
```

Then you should be good to go. The prepared statement should handle the data sanitization for you now.

Resouces:

1. [mysqli prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)
2. [mysqli bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)
3. [mysqli execute](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php)

Comment: I'm getting an error `Call to undefined method mysqli::bind_param()`

Comment: actually I think I fixed it, had to set the prepare to another variable $statement and call bind on that

Comment: @AbdulAhmad You're totally right. I omitted that in my initial answer. I've updated to reflect that fact; sorry for that!

Answer (score 2):

Can you post the CREATE TABLE statement for the user_saved_data table?

In general, I'd recommend just tracing it through and see where the data gets lost.

For example, can you echo the query you are generating and run in manually in MySQL? You may have a syntax error in the SQL being generated...

Comment: I understand that as you have a low reputation, you're not able to post comments, but this is for a reason. Please refrain from posting comments as answers. Once you have enough karma (50 or so), you can post comments. I won't downvote you, so that you don't have to climb the hill back, but please delete this.